# PHP link builder to avoid use of Java Script and hide the old URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm creating a login page that accepts a username and then redirects the user to log in. This is currently done, and works with the following Java Script.

```css
function process()
{
var url="https://example.com/users/profile" + document.getElementById("username").value;
location.href=url;
return false;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter your username</p>
<form onsubmit="return process();">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
```

I'd prefer to do this without using Java Script to support users that disable it, older browsers and to hide this from the source code of the page. The subdirectories are protected anyway but I just want the added compatibility.

I'm attempting to do this with PHP instead;

```html
<form action="/authenticate.php">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
```

I'm using the same form but have created a page called `authenticate.php` instead. All that `authenticate.php` contains is;

```html
<p>Authenticating…</p>
<?php 
$username = ["username"];
header("Location: https://example.com/users/profile/$username"); die();
?>
```

If `steve` was the input, I'd expect that to then redirect to `https://example.com/users/profile/steve` but it doesn't. I've set up redirects already to handle errors and the form translates text to lowercase anyway.

I'm just wondering why;

```
<?php 
    $username = ["username"];
    header("Location: https://example.com/users/profile/$username"); die();
    ?>
```

won't work with the addition to the URL but does work without the `$username` so that's the only error. I also tried `$username = $POST_["username"];` but that's not relevant and doesn't seem to work either. The current code takes me to `https://example.com/users/profile/Array`

If someone could advise on the correct way to do this I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: did you try `$_POST['username']`

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work either because there's an unexpected T_STRING. It links to the page but that's about it. Throws a 500 error on the page when loaded and sends you to `https://example.com/authenticate.php?username=steve` like a standard HTML form would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default form method is GET but the best practice is to mention it so you've to do:

```
<form action="/authenticate.php" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
</form>
```

And authenticate.php you need to get input value:

```
<p>Authenticating…</p>
<?php 
  $username = $_GET["username"];
  header("Location: https://example.com/users/profile/$username");
  die();
?>
```

Comment: That works. Thank you. I didn't think of Get because it's not what I usually use for form responses, this is a different use case. Excellent, thanks.

Comment: Ah! In programming most of the time we stuck in little problems which we already knew it but just stuck don't know why :D
It happens usually with me too.
@tryingtogethelp Happy Coding dear!

Comment: Didn't know how to tackle it so I appreciate that. Thanks again, have a lovely day :)